# Understanding Git Merges

Tags: git

I know this solution is somewhere, but I am having trouble understanding git.

I am a single developer and there are often no changes on other branches while I am using git.

Here is often what I do:

```
git branch changes
git checkout -b changes
/* changes occur */
git commit -m "Changes Occured"
/* Changes occur */
git commit -m "More Changes"
```

After this, i have the following visualization in my head:

```
  :
  | c2
  | |
  | c1
  | /
master
```

However, git gui shows this visualization

```
    :
    c2 changes
    |
    c1
    |
  master
```

I then merge my changes with master like so:

```
git checkout -b master
git merge changes
```

I have the following visualization:

```
:
| master, changes
|
| \
| c2
| |
| c1
| /
```

master

However, git gui shows:

```
:
| master, changes
c2
|
c1
|
```

master

Is this the expected behavior? Or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Side note: instead of making the code segments snippets, just indent them four spaces (or highlight them and press control-K in the browser editor).

Comment: Yes, this is expected **as long as no commits was made to master in the mean time**, this is called a "fast forward" merge. You *can* avoid it by asking the merge command to not do a fast-forward merge with `--no-ff` but in most cases you actually *want* the fast forward merge as this creates a simpler and more linear history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your visualization presupposes that there are more commits atop branch `master`:

```
c3 (master)
|
| c2 (changes)
| |
| c1
| /
c0
:
```

Or, equivalently, that branch names have some sort of permanent significance (they don't in Git: in Git, only *commits* matter; branch names are largely just silly things to accomodate mere humans, except for some special roles they have in keeping commits alive and helping to send them back and forth between different Gits).

Note also that I have also moved the branch labels to point to the *newest* commit (only).  This is how branch labels work in Git: they point to a single commit, and hence identify the *tip commit* of the branch.

If commit `c3` does not yet exist, Git notices that you have this arrangement:

```
c2 (changes)
|
c1
|
c0 (master)
:
```

in which commit `c0`, which is the tip of `master`, is *also* reachable from `c2`, which is the tip of `changes`.  This means that commit `c0` is on *both branches* (note that this is reachability thing is true even if `master` points to some commit `c3`, as in the top diagram).  Since you *do* have this arrangement, Git can "slide the name `master` forward in a fast-forward fashion", up the downward links that go from `c2` to `c1` and back to `c0`.  This—this thing that is not actually a merge at all—is the default action for `git merge` whenever it is possible.  If `master` already pointed to new commit `c3`, that would be impossible, and Git would have to do, and make, a "real merge" (do the merging action, and make a merge commit `c4`).

To force Git to make a merge *commit*—the *action*, the merge-as-a-verb, is still entirely unnecessary and Git doesn't bother—you can use `git merge --no-ff`.  This will make a new merge commit `c3` and move the `master` label up to point to that merge commit:

```
c3 (HEAD -> master)
|\
| c2 (changes)
| |
| c1
| /
c0
:
```

Note that only the *current* branch name, i.e., the label `master`, moves.  To note which label is current, we add the `HEAD` name.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no other commits on the main branch, git will opt to fast forward instead of making a merge commit.  If you don't like this behavior (many, like me, don't) and want to keep the branch history, you can merge with `git merge _branch_ --no-ff` to force git to make a merge commit.

Answer (score 1):

Branches in git are nothing but the history of their commits. They are not recorded themselves but merely point to the lastest one of those commits.

This is why

```
    :
    c2 changes
    |
    c1
    |
  master
```

looks the way it is displayed. There are only two commits, c1 and c2, and `changes` points to the second one of those, while `master` has no recorded history.

After a merge, `master` has also recorded the commits `c1` and `c2`. Since there were not commits exclusively on master before the merge occured, `master` and `changes` are no virtually the same, i.e. the record the same history of commits since from both points of view the same commits happened in the same order. That is (`c1`, `c2`), since the merge was done by fast-forward.